# I need the program to show the result after each year

Tags: c#

It only shows the end result.

For example - "Amount after 3. year - 1100 eur"

but I need it to show the result of year 1 and 2 as well.

```
int i; 
Double sum;

Console.Write("Starting amount: ");  
Double start = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Duration of deposit: ");  
int year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Annual interest rate: ");  
Double c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

for (i = 1; i < g; i++) ;
{
    Console.Write("Amount after " + i + ". year - ");
    sum = a * (1 + i * c);
    Console.WriteLine(sum + " eur");
}
```

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of the `for` loop so the `{}` afterwards isn't repeated. What is `a` and `g`?

Comment: if you are not familiar with syntax and how to end code blocks properly I would do some basic refresher reading on C# Basics also remove the `;` at the end of this line `for (i = 1; i < g; i++) ;`

Comment: Also probably you want i <= g overwise you end with duration of deposit-1 (since you start at 1).

Comment: **Pay attention to compiler warnings**. You should have gotten a warning explaining your mistake.

Comment: Are you doing simple interest or compound interest? (Right now this is computing the simple interest).

Comment: Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); will cause the program to crash if the user enters something other than a valid double. It'll also accept nonsensical values like -23.0. You should probably change this to include validation and handle invalid input more gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` after your `for` loop.

```
// No `;` at the end of the line of the loop
for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Iterate until condition is met
}
```

You even got a warning for it:
[image]

MSDN says about the body of the [for loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)'s body:

> The body of the loop consists of a statement, an empty statement, or a block of statements, which you create by enclosing zero or more statements in braces.

If you place a `;` at the end of that `for` loop line you are inserting an `empty` statement. it is like writing:

```
for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) ; // The empty scope is iterated until condition is met
for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) {} // Same as above

{
    //Now after loop ends the scope is executed and actually the {} is not needed  
}
```